# History.go(-1) not working for the page that has links to the sections of same page

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I am facing a problem. I have a web page where I use **back** button anchor link and the code used is `ONCLICK="history.go(-1)"`. The same page has many anchor links and the related sections.

When I go to a page containing **back** button and click **back** button immediately, then **back** button works fine.

If I go to a page containing **back** button, then hit anchor link that points to a section in the same page and then hit the **back** button, then it never goes to previous web page, instead goes to the section url.

Comment: This is how it should work. An anchor link is a valid part of history.

Comment: Thanks .. bazmegakapa. How to implement the above. any idea ?

Comment: Consider using location.replace() then for your anchor links.

Comment: Thanks .. Jack. How do to get the previous URL to use location.replace. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try a counter that counts how many times a "section" link is clicked

Maybe something like (with jQuery but maybe some kind person will go and change this code to nice plain JavaScript):

```
var count = 0;
var historyValue = -1;
$(".sectionlinks").click(function () {
    ++count;
    window.historyValue = -(count + 1);
})​
```

And all your section links have a `sectionlinks` class.

Then you can do on your back link:

```
<a onclick="history.go(historyValue)">My Back Link</a>
```

See this fiddle for a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RRcyF/2/

Answer (score 2):

Through the new History API, you can [manipulate the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

[History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) helps you achieve this in a cross-browser way.

I have quickly created a [small fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QumbZ/5/) that illustrates it working and uses jQuery for event handling (this is not production code, just a demo, works in my Chrome).

```
$('.anchor').click(function () {
    history.replaceState({}, '', this.href);
});
```

Comment: Thanks bazmegakapa. How can I manipulate the number of anchor link clicks in the same page. Can you suggest an idea.

Comment: @sridhar Added a little demo.

Answer (score 1):

If so you could use javascript to solve this by simply using this line.

Make use of the `history.go()` JavaScript function as below:

```
<a href="javascript:window.history.go(-1);">Go back</a>
```